# Whats the default permissions generator automatically of a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I create a model:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=26)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (   
            ("add_info", "Can view info"),  # C
            ("read_info", "Can view info"),  # R
            ("update_info", "Can update info"),  # U
            ("delete_info", "Can delete info")  # D
        )
```

When I makemigrations, but there comes error:

```
app07.Info: (auth.E005) The permission codenamed 'add_info' clashes with a builtin permission for model 'app07.Info'.
app07.Info: (auth.E005) The permission codenamed 'delete_info' clashes with a builtin permission for model 'app07.Info'.
```

So, when I create a user the model will create permissions automatically. But you see, the `READ` and `UPDATE` permissions are not `read_info` and `update_info`, so whats the default permissions of a model?

Answer (score 0):

From the [permission document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/):

**Default permissions**

> When django.contrib.auth is listed in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, it will ensure that three default permissions – add, change and delete – are created for each Django model defined in one of your installed applications.

Assuming you have an application with an app_label foo and a model named Bar, to test for basic permissions you should use:

```
add: user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')
change: user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
```